# Boostrap 4 Row within container-fluid to have same padding as a container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a website using bootstrap 4 and I've ran into a problem.

[image: A badly drawn image of what I want]

The page is a conatainer fluid as the header and footer backgrounds should spread to the edge of the page.

Within the header and footer a container is used for the menu and footer stuff so that everything is central.

The contens between the header and footer should work in a similar way (the background stretch to the edges) However I am using columns so that on one side it might be blue and the other white.  I want the content of these rows to be in line with the header footer (left edge of the menu in the header to be the same place as the text)

I have't got a clue where to start, I tried overlaying a container on top of the container-fluid but the rows didnt match up..

I've created this code pen of what I've got so far.

css:

```
    .rowoverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid homepage-text-plugin">

    <div class="row rowoverlay">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-5" style="background-color: green;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-7" style="background-color: red;">

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container ">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 " style="background-color: blue;">
                A text block
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-7" style="background-color: yellow;">
                More text<p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could style this with CSS flexbox. Perhaps you should have a look into it.  Here is a code snippet example of the layout from your badly drawn image lol.

```css
.row-example {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.row-1-left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.row-1-center {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row-1-right {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.row-2-left {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.row-2-right {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}

.row-3-left {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.row-3-right {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.row-4-left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.row-4-center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row-4-right {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid homepage-text-plugin">
  <div class="row-example">
    <div class="row-1-left"></div>

    <div class="row-1-center">
      <p>Header container</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row-1-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-example">
    <div class="row-2-left"></div>

    <div class="row-2-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-example">
    <div class="row-3-left"></div>

    <div class="row-3-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-example">
    <div class="row-4-left"></div>

    <div class="row-4-center"></div>

    <div class="row-4-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```